# Querying data view (Open) and grouping by date in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

I am trying to get the number of opens for each day (Example: April 15, April 16, April 17 and so on....)

| Date | Opens |
| --- | --- |
| Apr 15 | 17500 |
| Apr 16 | 5000 |
| Apr 17 | 200 |

I am using the below query, but not getting required results.

```
select distinct count (o.SubscriberKey), o.EventDate as date
from [_Open] o
inner join [Emails_Sent_on_April15] s
on o.JOBID= s.JOBID   and   s.BATCHID=o.BATCHID
where o.isunique = 1
group by cast (o.EventDate as date )
```

Could anyone help me know, how to modify the above query to get the results like in the table.

The problem is o.EventDate in select statement also has time

Comment: Have you tried casting the `o.EventDate` as a date in the select statement, just like you do in the group by statement?

Comment: yes, I tried this in Query Studio- getting "Field name cannot contain the character ) " error

Comment: Have you tried `cast(o.EventDate as date) AS DATE`? Maybe give it a go in Automation Studio?

Comment: Yes true works in Automation Studio but does not work in Query Studio..Thanks

Comment: While Query Studio is tempting to use due to its simplicity, it introduces additional inconsistencies -- both in parsing and functionality.  I'd recommend building this as a Query Activity and running it with an Automation as @zuzannamj suggested.

Comment: You can also try the convert function `convert(date, o.eventDate) date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a shift, I was able to get this to work correctly. If you have a high volume, this may certainly time out, but if you place a date range in it, should work:

```sql
select
count(o.SubscriberKey) as cnt, 
CONVERT(date,o.EventDate) as dte
from [_Open] o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT se.SubscriberKey FROM [_Sent] se WHERE se.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey)
and o.isunique = 1
group by CONVERT(date,o.EventDate)
```

And if you want it also by JobID to differentiate send jobs per day, you can do:

```sql
select
count(o.SubscriberKey) as cnt, 
CONVERT(date,o.EventDate) as dte,
CONVERT(nvarchar(max),o.JobID) as JobID
from [_Open] o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT se.SubscriberKey FROM [_Sent] se WHERE se.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey)
and o.isunique = 1
group by CONVERT(date,o.EventDate), CONVERT(nvarchar(max),o.JobID)
```

Just replace the `_Sent` DV (in my `EXISTS` statement) with your DE.